# PHP Mail form doesn't work when certain text is entered

Tags: php, html, email, post

I'm working on a PHP mail form and for some reason only certain text doesn't send through. It has me baffled and I can't even think of how to Google an answer.

For example, if I enter for the form:

```
 Name: Indiana Jones
 Number: 000
 Email: indiana@jones.com
```

The mail function won't work, however if I change the `000` to `999`, it works.
OR if I change the `indiana@jones.com` to `indiana@jones.net`, it suddenly works too.

Here are snippers, from my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">

Name<br />
<input style="width:878px;" type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
Best Contact Number<br />
<input style="width:415px;" type="text" name="number" id="number" required>
Email<br />
<input style="width:415px;" type="email" name="email" id="email" required>

</form>
```

And from my PHP (mail.php): (personal email addresses have been removed)

```
<?php
ini_set("SMTP","mail.email.com.au");
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'email@email.com.au'); 

$to = "email@email.com.au";
$subject = "Mail Form";

$message = "Name:" . "\n" . $_POST['name'] . "\n\n";
$message .= "Best Contact Number:" . "\n" . $_POST['number'] . "\n\n";
$message .= "Email:" . "\n" . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";
$headers = "From: Removed <email@email.com.au> \n";

if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you for your submission'); window.location.href = 'index.html';</script>";} 
else 
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('There was an error - please check all fields and try again'); window.location.href = 'index.html';</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Removing that `@` from `@mail` would help you a lot!

Comment: Try `$message .= "Best Contact Number:" . "\n" . (int)$_POST['number'] . "\n\n";`

Comment: I have removed the @ from @mail, however the problem persists. Have also tried Fred's response and it worked, but then I tried with another number (that wasn't 000) and I am coming back to the same error.

Comment: Instead of `$message .= "Email:" . "\n" . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";` try first assigning a variable to email. `$email=$_POST['email'];` then do `$message .= "Email: $email\n\n";`

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your file will make PHP output _all_ errors, including trivial ones. Always a good idea to do this during development – this might give us a few hints as to what the problem is.

Comment: Plus, the dots in `$message .= "Best Contact Number:" . "\n" . (int)$_POST['number'] . "\n\n";` might also be a factor. I would first assign a variable to "number", similar to above. `$phone=(int)$_POST['number'];` then do `$message .= "Best Contact Number: $phone\n\n";` and do the same for the "name".

Comment: I have tried adding error_reporting(E_ALL) but nothing shows. I think this is because mail only returns true/false so it won't give me any errors?

Fred - I just tried assigning variables for name, email, phone, but still receive the same result.
Am I able to post URL's here? Perhaps that may help identify my problem, if I link the page directly

Comment: It sounds like your mail provider might actually be blocking some things from going through.

Answer (score 0):

well, I just got a code that will make it work great .

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

        $email_to = "email@email.com.au";

        $email_subject = "Mail Form";
        function died($error) {

            // your error code can go here

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('There was an error because '); window.location.href = 'index.html';</script>";
            die();
        }
        // validation expected data exists

        if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

            !isset($_POST['number']) ||

            !isset($_POST['email'])) {

            died('<script type='text/javascript'>alert('There was an error - please check all fields and try again'); window.location.href = 'index.html';</script>');       

        }
        $name = $_POST['name']; // required

        $email = $_POST['email']; // required

        $number = $_POST['number']; // required

        $error_message = "";

        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

      if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

      }

        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

      if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

        $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

      }

      if(strlen($comments) < 0) {

        $error_message .= 'The Number you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

      }

      if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

        died($error_message);

      }

        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

        function clean_string($string) {

          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

        }
        $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

        $email_message .= "Number: ".clean_string($number)."\n";

    // create email headers

    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

    ?>
<!-- if sent successfuly -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you for your submission'); window.location.href = 'index.html';</script>

    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

You can add this code to display the errors for users

```
echo $error."<br /><br />";
```

Comment: Just my personal preference but you could write that code so much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the code Mahmoud, I used it and added some vars (pharmacy, time). I have tried the same entries but still cannot get the email to send. It says "Thank you for your submission" but the email never arrives. I am beginning to suspect it might not be the mail.php file.

Comment: Check your spam folder

Comment: No luck. I managed to get some emails to send through, but once I entered the same combination (Indian Jones, Indiana@jones.com, etc.) it failed.

Comment: It's very strange that it will work for 90% of the entries, but every now and then when I put in a test name or number it will fail.

Comment: that's weird , I think you will have to add a specified code for this string

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it turns out this was an Exchange server issue. I have no idea why it was letting some messages go through and filtering others, but our IT team sorted it out and had to allow the website's IP through.

Form is fully functional now though!